# What does it mean that the Fourier kernel is an exponentiated bilinear form?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, fourier-analysis

Terence Tao mentions it in [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/40382/74150) to explain the intuition of why the Fourier transform of a Gaussian is a Gaussian.

The Fourier kernel is $e^{i \omega x}=\cos \omega x + i \sin \omega x.$

Does the Re / Im components of the expression have anything to do with it, or is the concept that a Fourier transform is really an inner product of an infinitely dimensional vector space of functions?